# Hamilton's equations of motion

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism

One of hamilton's equations is $(\frac{\partial H}{\partial q} )_t = -(\frac{\partial p}{\partial t}) _q$. But isn't it $\frac{\partial L}{\partial q} = \frac{dp}{dt}$? If H = L(i.e. V = 0), what happens? Am I confusing which variable is fixed on the partial derivation?

Comment: If $V=0$ and the kinetic energy doesn't explicitly depend on $q$, then both of your equations will turn out to be zero

Comment: The double pendulum, which contains cos(q1-q2) in its kinetic lagrangian, is a counterexample of that statement.

Answer (score 1):

If $H=L$, then
$$
L=H=\sum_{a}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}^{a}}\dot{q}^{a}-L
$$
so that
$$
L=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{a}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}^{a}}\dot{q}^{a}
$$
from which follows
$$
H=L=\sum_{a}\ A_{a}(q)\ (\dot{q}^{a})^{2}
$$
You can check by yourself that you get the same equations from both the Lagrangian and the Hamiltonian formalism:
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\ A_{a}(q)\ \dot{q}^{a}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{b}\frac{\partial A_{b}}{\partial q^{a}}\ (\dot{q}^{b})^{2}
$$
where
$$
p_{a}=2\ A_{a}(q)\ \dot{q}^{a}
$$